# Stop artifactory api paging

Tags: artifactory

I have a script that searches through our NPM packages in Artifactory.  Over the years,  this has become quite large and the results are paging now.  As a result, the script is failing if what I am looking for is not on the first page.

I really, really don't want to re-write the script to handle this.

Is there a way to turn paging off in Artifatory?

Comment: I dont think so there is such option available but will search more on this. Also how are you searching ? using api or using aql ?

Comment: Using the api. Currently the script gets all the versions of a package.  Our solution so far is to delete old versions.  But this is not a long term solution.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use aql for searching the artifacts it would be Kind of re writing but I think the efforts would be less as aql supports sorting based on different criteria is advanced than api

Comment: Which API are you using in the script for finding the packages?